# Why does fancy indexing take so long for my large HDF5 data set?

Tags: python, hdf5, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D dataset that is stored in an HDF5 file with reasonable chunking. I access it as follows:

```
f = h5py.File("mydata.h5", "r")
data  = f.get("mydata")
```

where data.shape ~ (1.e6, 3000) and data.dtype = 'float32'

I want to create a subset based on a 1D list of valid indices in the first dimension:

```
valid_mask = np.load("valid.npy")  # values 1 or 0, length ~ 1.e6, np.sum(valid_mask) = 300000
valid_indices = np.where(valid_mask)
data_clean = data[valid_indices]
```

Now, the above code works if I limit the length of valid_indices to a fraction of the total list; e.g., `valid_indices = np.where(valid_mask[:maxlength]`.  In fact, it's very fast if `maxlength=10000`.  But it becomes extremely slow as `maxlength` increases. In particular, it takes about 1 minute for `maxlength=100000` (about 10% of the total dataset), but it takes seven times as long if I increase `maxlength` by a mere factor of three, and it doesn't terminate after even a full hour once `maxlength` approaches `len(valid_mask)`

I realize that `data` needs to be read from the HDF5 file on disk as it's being subsetted, but to do this for the entire data set is taking *far* longer than it would take to simply read sequentially through the original 12 GB file.

I'm starting to suspect that using a brute-force `for` loop would be faster than what I'm trying to do above, but I have no idea why.  Any insight into why this is bogging down would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at your memory usage while running this? Some numpy functions have a really high memory overhead (`genfromtxt` for example bit me once) and you might run into your swap space / page file which greatly decreases performance.

Comment: According to System Monitor on my Mac, it's currently using a roughly constant 1GB of memory when `imax` is equal to a million.  This is less than a third of the memory I would expect `data_clean` to require, and it's well below the 16GB of RAM.  There no apparent memory pressure.

Comment: Also, CPU for the process is running at 100%, so that seems to be the limiting factor.  But again, I have no idea why.

Comment: I don't know, if this is even handled differently under the hood, but you might try `data_clean = data[valid_mask == 1]`

Comment: I'm inclined to think this is due to chunking. What is a "reasonable" chunk size? Is it possible to do an experiment with a contiguous dataset as well?

Comment: @bnaecker I thought numpy arrays had to be contiguous.

Comment: This is an HDF5 file, datasets from which behave like numpy arrays.  It's not a `memmap`ed array in this case, which I think does have to be contiguous.

Comment: The chunking is done in the HDF5 library, during reading from disk.

Comment: @bnaecker That sounds very plausible then. If it was contiguous data, I would see no reason for this behavior.

Comment: Datasets do not have to be contiguous on disk. You specifically say it is "chunked", which has a [certain meaning in HDF5-world](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/Advanced/Chunking/).

Comment: The chunk option I used when creating the file is `chunks=(512, nwvnum)`, where `nwvnum` is just the size of the second dimension.   So operations progressing sequentially through the first dimension should just be reading contiguous chunks, and there shouldn't be any repeat reads of any chunk, if I'm understanding things correctly.

Comment: @GrantPetty That means that data from the full array, which has leading dimension ~1e6, is grouped into chunks of size 512. So there are about 1900 chunks on disk, potentially stored in many places throughout your actual drive. If you know the size of the dataset beforehand, it can help in situations like this to keep it contiguous.

Comment: @bnaecker Would a mere 1900 chunks on disk explain the very long execution time?  Again, the process seems to be CPU-limited, not I/O or memory limited. Also, I don't think the chunking alone would explain why the time seems to go with something like the square (or worse) of `maxlength`.

Comment: @eike.  I'm trying `data_clean = data[valid_mask == 1, :]` right now, but so far, at least, it doesn't seem to be behaving any differently.   I'll try letting it run indefinitely while I eat lunch and do other things and see whether it ever completes at all.

Comment: @GrantPetty I'm not sure. I just ran a quick test, and it's definitely slower to index a chunked dataset, all else being equal. But I don't see quite as poor scaling as you do. The indexing you just tried is equivalent, so I'm not surprised you see the same behavior. What happens if you read the whole dataset into memory, and then subset using NumPy indexing? As in: `data.value[valid_indices]`? Also, what version of HDF5/h5py are you using?

Comment: Welp, there's this: https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/1067 :)

Comment: @bnaecker `data_clean = data.value[valid_mask == 1,:]` worked and completed in a mere 3 minutes.  But it was only possible because I had (barely) enough RAM to accommodate the whole data set.